# Posting images to Facebook wall (JS SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a system that creates/exports some images, and would like to post in on the Facebook wall. Currently what we do is post them to the user's album (using multipart/form-data request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos). But is there a way to make them end up on user's wall (or some of his friend's wall) instead of photo albums?
If not -- is it possible to get a link to newly posted image and add it to the wall?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){        
            FB.ui({ method : 'feed', 
                    message: userPrompt,
                    link   :  hrefLink,
                    caption:  hrefTitle,
                    picture: URLToPicture
           });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the problem is that we don't have URL to picture, as it's not hosted anywhere. We have it's binary content, and add it to the user's album currently.